# Why does the anova function not read the result of the aov function in subdivided parcels?

Tags: anova

resultado<-aov(dados$PROD~dados$FAC1 + Error(dados$FAC1) + dados$FAC2 + dados$FAC1*dados$FAC2)

anova(resultado)

Error in UseMethod("anova") :

method not applicable for 'anova' applied to an object of class "c('aovlist', 'listof')"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.